# Google sheets: how can I filter data in a sheet, based on the sheet's name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm a newby at Google Sheets, so I probabily am solving my problem in the longes way, forgive me.

I have a workbook with some sheets, each sheet has (obviously) a name: Supplier1, Supplier2,etc.

In another sheet (named "Main") I have a table with data validation: my aim is that whenever in that data validation I put the name that corresponds to one of the sheet's name, the "Main" sheet populates with the data that there are in that sheet.

Let's make an example to clarify the situation.
I have in the "Main" sheet a data validation that contains the values "Supplier1" and "Supplier2".
I also have other two sheets, named "Supplier1" and "Supplier2".
I would like that when I put in the data validation the value "Supplier1", the data that are currently in the "Supplier1" sheet are copied in the "Main" sheet.

Should I use formulas or implement a script?

Thank you
D

I've alredy tried with Filter function but it obviously doesn't work.
I don't know how to make a reference on a sheet without having a fixed name (it could change because of the data validation). I 'm currently trying with INDIRECT but it's not so easy.

Comment: Take a look at INDIRECT formula

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula that will get the first column of a sheet.

I create a sheet Main with the name of the sheet I want the values from in cell B1.  Then there is a formula in cell A3.  If I change the name of the sheet the results will change.

[image]